# Resources that bring out interesting scientific/historic/academic related discussions from the daf?

Tags: history, product-recommendation, torah-study, science, talmud-bavli

I have a relative that invests a few hours a day learning daf yomi, yet he recently admitted that he does this solely because he believes it's a good thing thing to do but not because he actually enjoys it. The sad part is that he actually loves reading information and has various areas of interests yet he doesn't see the Talmud as a possible source for such pursuits. I'm wondering if anyone has any good resources that bring up interesting academic discussions relating to the daf, whether historical, scientific or other. Preferably resources that get their information from the actual daf as I think he would appreciate the daf more if he could be taught to view it as an actual source of interesting information. But any resource in that direction would be appreciated. I don't think it needs to be overly academic, just interesting.

Comment: http://www.talmudology.com/

Comment: It's for just a single sugya, but there's Robert Aumann's paper called _Game Theory in the Talmud._ It's freely available online.

Comment: My grandfather a"h, who was an economics professor, wrote many papers and gave over many lectures and shiurim that connected Torah and economics and Talmud and economics. I could probably dig up some of those, if you'd like. They're mostly in Hebrew, though.

Comment: I'll add that Steinsaltz gemaras often have useful little tidbits on page borders that add historical/biological/etc context to the sugiya.

Comment: @Loewian talmudology is phenomenal. You should make that an answer.

Comment: @Loewian talmudology is exactly the type of answer I was looking for though I need a resource that covers a bit more of the tractate.

Comment: @Harel13 Thank you for that considerate offer but I dont think economics is one of his particular interests. Regarding your Stiensaltz suggestion, I just purchased a pdf version of one tractate just to check it out but i haven't gotten a chance to look yet.

Comment: Thank you all so much. please keep the suggestions coming.

Answer (score 5):

> [Jewish History in Daf Yomi](https://alldaf.org/series/jewish-history/3940) is a series of bite-sized lectures related to the Daf, delivered daily by renowned Jewish History expert, Dr. Henry Abramson.

Comment: Thank you, that is a great suggestion! I'm wondering if their are any resources that offer just a bit more than bite-sized.